# Maplace + Rails 4 receiving dates dynamically

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3

I'm using maplace.js with Rails 4, its pretty. Is almost all work how I want, but I need, onclick in even icon take the show_infowindow (this a option the maplace.js), but I don't know! (html = show_infowindow)
This is my code:

```
 new Maplace({
   locations: #{@localizacoes.to_json(:only => [:latitude, :longitude, :nome]).gsub('latitude', 'lat').gsub('longitude', 'lon').gsub('nome',     'title')},
   map_div : '#gmap-dropdown',
   shared: {
     html: '#{@localizacoes.find(params[:id]).created_at}' 
   }
 }).Load();
```

The error is:
 **Coundn't find Localizacao without an ID**

Please, someone help me? I'm trying more than 1 week! Thanks!

Comment: where you getting this params[:id], can you give more information?

Comment: Well, my controllers, models, all this default, I just add libraries maplace and put it code. And, when i put: @localizacoes.find(1).created_at, work! but I dont wanna this, I need get dynamically, because I have more than 1 result.

Comment: Take a look: https://github.com/eltonsantos/maps_rails